# Getting new functionality in Google App Engine with Django

Tags: python, django, html, google-app-engine

I am trying to get some HTML5 components into Django using the GAE.
I appreciate that it's not supported, but sites such as

http://forrst.com/posts/HTML5_Form_Widgets_in_Django-mTT

imply that I can do it the Django way. Which should someway of getting towards this rather than using the bare HTML. However I can't seem to expose the right modules on loading with

```
from django.forms.widgets import Input
```

I get the following:

```
django undefined, Input undefined

<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named widgets
      args = ('No module named widgets',)
      message = 'No module named widgets' 

However is one does help(django.forms.widgets) 

NAME
    django.newforms.widgets - HTML Widget classes

FILE
    /home/xxx/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/newforms/widgets.py

CLASSES
    __builtin__.object
        Widget
            CheckboxInput
            MultiWidget
                SplitDateTimeWidget
            Select
                NullBooleanSelect
                RadioSelect
            SelectMultiple
                CheckboxSelectMultiple
            Textarea
    Input(Widget)
        FileInput
        HiddenInput
            MultipleHiddenInput
        PasswordInput
        TextInput
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You're running Django 0.96. That's pretty much prehistoric. If google app engine supports it, switch to a later version. It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: app engine supports up to django 1.3 and 0.96, 1.2 and 1.3 are distributed with the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the correct version of Django, specify using use_library(), documented here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html

You most likely want to use 1.3

However, note that Django models don't work on App Engine.  It looks like you're using forms, which should be ok on their own, but if you're using ModelForms, you'll have to use djangoforms.ModelForm instead, which work with the App Engine db models.

The other option is to use Django-nonrel, which allows you to use Django models on App Engine, though there are some limits to the functionality.